# is there any difference between these three logarithms?

Tags: calculus, logarithms, asymptotics, computer-science

is there any difference between $\log(n)^{\log(n)}$ vs $(\log n)^{\log n}$ vs $\log n^{\log n} $ from asymptotic growth rate? maybe all the same. I doubt about notation.

maybe this is very basic or crazy question, but I need to know.

Comment: The notation of $\log(n)^{\log n}$ and $\log n^{\log n}$ are both ambiguous.  $\log(n)^{\log n}$ *probably* means $(\log n)^{\log n}$ but it could mean $\log[n^{\log n}]$.  $\log n^{\log n}$ *probably* means $\log[n^{\log n}]$ but it could mean  $(\log n)^{\log n}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One must be careful, there is a crucial difference between $$(\log n)^{\log n}$$ and $$\log n^{\log n}$$ The exponent rule for the logarithm can be applied to this last one to obtain: $$\log n^{\log n}= \log n \log n=(\log n)^2 \neq (\log n)^{\log n}$$

Comment: please add details for the first expression in question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is. Simple thumb rule: **Power on the operand comes to side.**

Suppose there is a logarithm exprerssion $\log_a{x}, a\neq1, x\gt0$. I am going to refer $x$ as the operand.Now, if an exponent $y$ is present on the operand $x$, then:

$$\log_a{(x^{y})} = y\log_a{x}$$

Proof:
Here I am considering $y\ge0$ (since I am assuming growth rates require only positive integral domain). A similar proof is present for negative y too.
$$\log_a{(x^{y})} = \log_a{(x\times x \times x\times x...y\ times)} = \log_a{x}+\log_a{x}+\log_a{x}...y \ times = y\log_a{x}$$

The other one is simply

$$(\log_a{x})^y = \log_a{x}\times\log_a{x}\times\log_a{x}...y \ times$$

**EDIT**:
$\log{(n)}^{\log{(n)}}$ is a little ambiguous. If up to me, I would consider it as an exponent on the operand (just because parenthesis are there about n)

**EDIT 2**:
To put it simply, one growth is **polynomial$\times$logarithmic** and other **logarithmic exponentiated to logarithmic**. To find the actual difference, you could find the ratio of their limits as n$\to\infty$. Then you can compare their relative growth rates.

Comment: Your proof is valid only when $y$ is a positive integer.

Comment: @BrianCheung , I know, but the formula is valid nonetheless for negative $y$ too. And since OP is asking about asymptotic growth rates, n has to be positive. Still, I will edit it in the answer